# Ruby: Receive and print JSON object

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, sinatra

I want to receive a JSON object using Ruby. I've written this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
  "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

And I'm sending:

```
var options = {
                  host: 'localhost',
                  port: 4567,
                  path: '/',
                  method: 'POST'
                };

var myFirstJSON = { "payload" : { "headers" : 
                                            [{ "from" : from,
                                                "to"  : to,
                                                "subject" : subject }],
                                "body"    : 
                                            [{ "primeira_parte" : primeira_parte,
                                                "segunda_parte" : segunda_parte,
                                                "terceira_parte": terceira_parte }]
                                }};
            req.write(JSON.stringify(myFirstJSON));
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError - can't convert nil into String:


{"{\"payload\":{\"headers\":"=>{"{\"from\":\"test@test.com\",\"to\":\"test@test.com\",\"subject\":\"Testing\"}"=>{",\"body\":"=>{"{\"primeira_parte\":\"The following message to <test@test.com> was undeliverable.\\r\\nThe reason for the problem:\\r\\n5.1.0 - Unknown address error 553-'sorry, this recipient is not in my valid"=>"\\r\\nrcptto list (#5.7.1)'\",\"segunda_parte\":\"Final-Recipient: rfc822"}}}, "test@test.com\\r\\nAction: failed\\r\\nStatus: 5.0.0 (permanent failure)\\r\\nRemote-MTA: dns"=>nil, "216.75.35.163"=>{"\\r\\nDiagnostic-Code: smtp"=>nil}, "5.1.0 - Unknown address error 553-'sorry, this recipient is not in my validrcptto list (#5.7.1)' (delivery attempts: 0)\",\"terceira_parte\":\"Received: from unknown (HELO aws-bacon-delivery-svc-iad-1020.vdc.amazon.com) ("=>{"10.144.21.123"=>{")\\r\\n  by na-mm-outgoing-6102-bacon.iad6.amazon.com with ESMTP"=>nil}}, "16 Apr 2011 14:11:15  0000\\r\\nReturn-Path: 0000012f5eb1cab3-09564031-57ef-4136-8cd7-9f368c5acd7d-000000@email-bounces.amazonses.com\\r\\nDate: Sat, 16 Apr 2011 14:23:20  0000\\r\\nFrom: tiago@tiagop.org\\r\\nTo: test@test.com\\r\\nMessage-ID: <0000012f5eb1cab3-09564031-57ef-4136-8cd7-9f368c5acd7d-000000@email.amazonses.com>\\r\\nSubject: Testing\\r\\nMime-Version: 1.0\\r\\nContent-Type: text/plain"=>nil, "\\r\\n charset"=>"UTF-8\\r\\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\\r\\nX-AWS-Outgoing: 199.255.192.79\\r\\n\\r\\n<html><body><p> Helllooo </p></body></html>\\r\\n\\r\\n\"}]}}"}
```

Comment: can you show what you get with puts params.inspect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a route like this:

```
post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  "I got JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

You're not form encoding the data, therefore it doesn't get set in params.

Comment: I get this when receiving the JSON object: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2011 15:57:08] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1371 0.0020
practivate.adobe.com - - [17/Apr/2011:15:57:08 WEST] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1371
- -> /

Comment: Which is fine, it means the request succeeded. What did you get returned to you is the more apropos question? I.e, if you print out the response you get back from the socket, what does that contain? What you expect?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Thanks. Can you explain why my first code was wrong? I still don't get it. Thanks

Comment: Because you were expecting it to be encoded as a parameter in the HTTP request, which isn't how you wrote it. You wrote it such that it would write the json out over the body (as it should in most cases), which means on the other end, the end that receives the POST, it needs to read it from the body, otherwise it won't get the data in the format you expect. When building APIs, you almost always want to write the json out in the body, not encoded as parameters.

Comment: How would I write the same JSON as parameter? because that was I trying to achieve to create a Web Hook like GitHub has. Thank you for your great answer.

Comment: I'm not strong with Javascript, so I can't tell you how to do it that way with code. But what you want to do is figure out a way to encode parameters into a request before you issue that request. Set a `key=someValue` mapping in the request parameters, where `key` is what will be referenced in Sinatra's params hash, and `someValue` will be whatever you set for key.